# The partial preorder on $\mathbb N$ generated by the finite axioms of choice

Tags: nt.number-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $\mathsf C_n$ denotes the statement:

*for any family $\mathcal F$ of $n$-element sets there exists a choice function (i.e., a function $f:\mathcal F\to\bigcup\mathcal F$ such that $f(F)\in F$ for all $F\in\mathcal F$).*

It is known that $\mathsf C_2\Rightarrow \mathsf C_4$ in ZF.

This fact suggests introducing a partial preorder $\preceq$ on the set $\mathbb N$ of positive integers defined by $n\preceq m$ if $\mathsf C_m\Rightarrow \mathsf C_n$ in ZF.

Also we can write that $n\cong m$ if $\mathsf C_n\Leftrightarrow \mathsf C_m$.

It is easy to show that $n\preceq m$ if $n$ divides $m$. So, $1\preceq n$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$ and $2\preceq n$ for any even number $n$.

On the other hand, $\mathsf C_2\Rightarrow \mathsf C_4$ implies that $2\cong 4$.

What else is known about the partial preorder $\preceq$? Maybe there exists a precise (arithmetic) description of this preorder.

A  more specific question: is $2^n\cong 2$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$?

I know that similar questions were studied by Mostowski, Tarski, Truss, Jech so maybe the answer is already known?

Comment: It's not a partial order, since $\sf AC(2)\iff AC(4)$. (You are right to say preorder, though.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, sorry, Asaf! I had in mind preorder (and wrote so in the body of the question). Now I will fix the title.

Comment: I had a conversation with Lorenz Halbeisen about this once. I don't remember the conclusion, though. There's some information in Jech "The Axiom of Choice" (Ch. 7), but I don't remember if there were any significant developments after that.

Comment: Have you seen https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202586/axiom-of-choice-for-sets-of-finite-sets by the way?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I have seen this question, but my interest to this question was motivated by a yesterday discussion with one of my coauthors  who currently reads some book in Set Theory (probably Jech's "Axiom of Choice") and told me about $AC(2)=> AC(4)$ so I started to think about this question (without extensive search in the literature) and hoped that asking this question on mathoverflow will give me more quick and complete answer than my own browsing through internet.

Comment: “Theorem 3” in Mathieu Baillif’s answer to his own question gives a complete description of the preorder, doesn’t it?

Comment: Let me make a notational remark. Often $\mathsf{AC}(X)$ denotes the axiom of choice restricts to subsets of $X$. In which case $\mathsf{AC}(n)$ is a theorem of ZF for any finite $n$. I have a strong preference to the convention $\mathsf{AC}^A_B(C)$ where $B$ is the size of the family, $A$ is the size of the members in the family, and $C$ is the superset of the sets in the family, along with the understanding that omitting any of the parameters implies a universal quantifier.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok. I will change notation from $AC(n)$ to $AC_n$, which is more near to that from Jech who denote it by $C_n$ (but $C_n$ is ovecharged, for example it can denote the cyclic group of order $n$).

Comment: That also works, good. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Jech's "The Axiom of Choice", at the end of Chapter 7, he formulates the following condition on two natural numbers $n>m$:

> (S) There is *no* decomposition of $n$ into $p_1+\ldots+p_s=n$ such that $p_i>m$ is a prime number for all $i$.

And he goes on to prove that if $\mathsf{C}_k$ holds for all $k\leq m$, then (S) implies $\mathsf{C}_n$, and moreover if (S) fails, then there is a model of $\mathsf{C}_k$ for all $k\leq m$, but $\lnot\mathsf{C}_n$.

---

So, for example, if the Goldbach conjecture is true, then $\mathsf{C}_2$ implies nothing more than $\mathsf{C}_4$, since in that case every even number other than $2$ is the sum of two primes, and other than $4$ these primes have to be odd.

So this is now a question about number theory, rather than set theory, and I will let the experts in that field make their remarks.

*Emil Jeřábek notes in the comments that every $n\geq 8$ is the sum of some amount of $3$s and $5$, both prime and both odd, so $\mathsf{C}_2$ does not extend its reach beyond $\mathsf{C}_4$.*

Comment: Every number $\ge8$ is the sum of a suitable amount of 3s and 5s (Frobenius coin problem), so you don’t need Goldbach’s conjecture.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. I do like the Goldbach conjecture connection though. But I'll edit this in. Thanks!

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the answer. And what follows (or does not follow) from $AC_3$?

Comment: @Taras: That's a harder question, since Jech's book only gives the condition assuming choice from families of pairs as well. So I can't quite answer that. (I think this was part of the aforementioned chat with Lorenz, by the way.)

Comment: @TarasBanakh The criterion from Mathieu Baillif’s post shows that $\mathit{AC}_3$ does not imply anything besides itself and $\mathit{AC}_1$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I can't see it: which part of Mathieu Baillif's post (=I suppose [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/203361)) says anything about $\mathsf{C}_3$ (or $\mathit{AC}(\{3\})$ or whatever it may be called) not implying anything else?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen As I already wrote above, Theorem 3, in the special case $Z=\{m\}$, gives a completely general finitary combinatorial criterion equivalent to $ZF\vdash C_m\to C_n$. The general statement is a bit unwieldy, but it’s quite easy to apply it to $m=3$. (Since 3 is not a nontrivial sum of numbers $>1$, and any group whose size is divisible by 3 contains an element of order 3, the criterion boils down to: any fixpoint-free subgroup $G\le S_n$ has size divisible by 3. So, it is enough to find a cyclic counterexample for $n\ne1,3$, i.e., write $n$ as a sum of numbers $>1$ not divisible by 3.)

Comment: Expanding on Emil's observation, results of Sylvester and others (using observation and results on prime gaps if needed) give that n not having such a decomposition means n is not bigger than m^2.  Gerhard "Well, Not That Much Bigger Anyway" Paseman, 2018.07.05.